# nominatim with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, street-address, nominatim

I have a simple code to display a map of Openstreetmaps via Openlayers based on latitude/longitude:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('#map');
var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(geo.lng,geo.lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
var zoom = 14; 

map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(position, zoom);

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );        
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));
map.addLayer(markers);
```

What i now would like to do is displaying a map not based on lat/lng but just with an address, perhaps via OpenStreetMap nominatim.
So i have the code above and an address string e.g. "country, state, city", without street/-nr. How do i point the map to that city?

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, take a look at the country,city and format parameters:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?country=England&city=London&format=json

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Gazetteer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gazetteer) for this, which is basically a dictionary filled with place names and location identifiers. There are several ways to use [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) for this purpose or other GeoCoders. Here is an example for Openlayers and OSM using [OpenRouteService](http://www.openrouteservice.org/): http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/openls.html

Comment: is there no way to just get the lat/lng from a search like this: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=England+London ... afaik there is some way to get the response as json, maybe there is lat/lng included?